# How to return List<int> from an event

Tags: c#, list, events

I have a custom delegate like this:

```
public delegate List<int> ExpandableChildrenGetterDelegate(string parentId);
```

and my event from this delegate is:

```
public event ExpandableChildrenGetterDelegate ExpandableChildrenGetting;
```

but Visual Studio designer cannot generate method for this action. And I must change my delegate to:

```
public delegate IEnumerable ExpandableChildrenGetterDelegate(string parentId);
```

How I can solve this, that I explicit write `List<int>` instead of 
`IEnumerable`?

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that Visual Studio is trying to rationalize that there are N copies of `List<int>` that it needs to return from the event.  One from every handler that receives the value.  Hence it's defaulting to the C# 1.0 behavior of non-generic `IEnumerable`.

The best way to get this kind of information from an event is to make it a part of the `EventArgs` implementation.  Then every handler can just append to it directly

```
class MyEventArgs : EventArgs {
  public List<int> ExpandableChildren = new List<int>();
}

public delegate void ExpandableChildrenGetterDelegate(
  string parentId, 
  MyEventArgs e);
```

The consumers of the event would just edit the list in the event args instead of returning a new one

Comment: this approach is good,but i create a component that other users will work with this component, and i need to show obviously whatever exist in event and need to return.